# Simple regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why this isn't working:

```
Regex = /\/(.*?)_/

String = 
hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here
```

... this works, but I can't use it in bash:

```
ISSUE_ID=$(sed 's/\/(.*?)_/\1/g' <<< $CURRENT_HEAD)

echo "$ISSUE_ID" // outputs nothing
```

**Actual example**:

```
➜  the-project-5.7 git:(hotfix/project-1229_reports-results-post-shows-all-post-results-instead-of-the-selected-project) echo $(sed 's/\/\(.*?\)_/\1/g' <<< $(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD))
hotfix/project-1229_reports-results-post-shows-all-post-results-instead-of-the-selected-project
➜  the-project-5.7 git:(hotfix/project-1229_reports-results-post-shows-all-post-results-instead-of-the-selected-project)
```

Comment: show the actual `$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)` output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here`

Comment: Your code references a variable that it does not define (`$CURRENT_HEAD`), shows an invalid assignment for `Regex` and `String`, uses input data that is not shown...  Could you please make sure you show the actual code, the one that outputs nothing (including no error messages from Bash).

Comment: @Fred updated the description

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using? Are you sure you do not need to escape the parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not valid for `sed`. The minor problem is that capture groups use backslashed parentheses `\(`...`\)`; bare parentheses are literal.

The more significant problem is that `sed` doesn't recognize the non-greedy qualifier `?` on quantifiers like `*`. You can get around that by being more explicit - instead of "the shortest sequence of any characters at all before an underscore", you can just explicitly ask for a sequence of non-underscores, like this:

```
sed 's,/\([^_]*\)_,\1,g'
```

(I also changed the delimiter from `/` to `,`; `sed` doesn't care what character you use, and this avoids a tiny bit of [leaning-toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)).

That should now match, but it only replaces the part of the string that matches the pattern. If you want to throw away everything that comes before and after as well, then you have to make the pattern match the entire string. The easiest way to do that is by adding `.*` on either side:

```
sed 's,.*/\([^_]*\)_.*,\1,g'
```

You can also use `-E` to turn on extended regular expressions - among other things, that flips the meanings of backslashed and non-backslashed parentheses. It still doesn't get you greediness qualifiers, but it does let you use even fewer backslashes:

```
sed -E 's,.*/([^_]*)_.*,\1,g'
```

Comment: Thanks, but all it did was just removed all the `/` from the output, thats all.

Comment: @3zzy It should also have removed the `_`. If that's not what you wanted, you need to fix your question.

Comment: If you want to get just the part in parentheses and throw away the rest of the string, that's different from your original regex, too. See if my edit helps.

Comment: From `hotfix/project-1229_reports-results-post-shows-all-post-results-instead-of-the-selected-project` I need to extract `project-1229`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to transform `hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here` into `ABC-181`. Your code has some issues:

- it uses a Perl-style regex, not a sed regex
- the substitution only removes `/` and `_` anyway

Fortunately you don't even need a regex:

```
# remove everything up to first '/'
ISSUE_ID="${CURRENT_HEAD#*/}"
# remove everything after '_'
ISSUE_ID="${ISSUE_ID%%_*}"
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion for details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what operating system you're using or what variant of `sed` it comes with, but I note that your regular expression appears to contain a non-greedy modifier for `*`, which sed *probably* doesn't support.  Note that `sed` is not `bash`, and different versions of sed are installed on, say, FreeBSD, OS X, Linux Cygwin or HP/UX, all of which can run bash.

If the output you're looking for is `ABC-181`, you might use:

```
$ CURRENT_HEAD="hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here"
$ ISSUE_ID=$(sed -E 's:.*/([^_]+).*:\1:g' <<<"$CURRENT_HEAD")
$ echo "$ISSUE_ID"
ABC-181
```

Alternately, you can do this in **bash** rather than in sed:

```
$ [[ $CURRENT_HEAD =~ .*/([^_]+).* ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here" [1]="ABC-181")'
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
ABC-181
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCRE for example if your grep knows the `-P`.

```
CURRENT_HEAD="hotfix/ABC-181_some_text_here"
ISSUE_ID=$(grep -oP '/\K.*?(?=_)' <<<"$CURRENT_HEAD")
echo "$ISSUE_ID"
```